# Scrape table from html (<tr> and ID method not working)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to do a web scrape of a table from this website: http://pusatdata.kontan.co.id/reksadana/produk/469/Schroder-90-Plus-Equity-Fund

Specifically the grey table with the headers "TANGGAL/NAB/DIVIDEN/DAILY RETURN (%)".

Below is the code that I use:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = "http://pusatdata.kontan.co.id/reksadana/produk/469/Schroder-90-Plus-Equity-Fund"

page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('div',id='table_flex')

print (table.text)
```

But no output was generated at all. Appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Find element with XPATH equaling to `div#table div table`. With `selenium` or `BeutifulSoap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't get the results you expect from your code, you need to backtrack to figure out where your code broke.

In this case, your first step would be to check the value of table. As it turns out, table is not None (which would signify a bad selector/soup.find call), so you at least know that you got that much right.

Instead, what you'll notice is that the table_flex div is empty. This isn't terribly surprising to me, but let's pretend I don't know anything and this doesn't make any sense. So the next step would be to pull up a browser and to double check that the DOM (via your browser's inspect tool) has content in the table_flex div.

It does, so now you have to do some real digging. If you run a simple search on the DOM in the inspect window for "table_flex", you'll first see the div that we already know about, but then you'll see some Javascript/jQuery further down the page that references "#table_flex".

This Javascript is part of a $.ajax() call (which you would google and find out is basically a query to a webserver for information). You'll also note that $("#table_flex") has an html() method (which, after more googling, you find out sets the html content for a particular element).

And now we have your answer for why the div is empty: when the webserver is queried for that page, the server sends back a document that has a blank table. The querying party is then expected to execute the Javascript to fill in the rest of the page. Generally speaking, Python modules don't run Javascript (for several reasons), so the table never gets populated.

This tends to be standard operating procedure for dynamic content, as "template" webpages can be cached and quickly distributed (since no additional information is needed) and then the rest of the information is supplied as the user needs it. This can also allow the same document to be used for multiple urls and query arguments without having to generate new documents.

Ultimately, what will  probably be easiest for you is to determine whether you can access that API directly yourself and simply query that url instead.

Answer (score 0):

There was no ouput generated because there is no text within the `<div>` with the id `table_flex`. So this shouldn't be a surprise.

The ”table” in question can be found under a `<div>` with the id `manajemen_reksadana`.  The two rows are not directly under that `<div>` and the whole ”table” is made of `<div>`s, so it's best to navigate to the known header/label texts, and address the `<div>` containing the value relative to the `<div>` with the header/label text:

```
fund_management_node = soup.find('div', id='manajemen_reksadana')
for label_text in ['PRODUK', 'KATEGORI', 'NAB', 'DAILY RETURN']:
    label_node = fund_management_node.find(text=label_text).parent
    print(label_node.find_next_sibling('div').text)
```